# Is it possible for my Activity to send generated touch/motion events to its child views?

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` that generates some `MotionEvent`s (via `MotionEvent.obtain()`). I'd like to pass these generated touch/motion events to the `Activity`'s children views. From the docs, `Activity.onTouchEvent()` is only called when one of the child views doesn't handle the event, which means I can't call that to pass the generated touch event to the children.

Is there a way to send a generated touch event *from the parent `MainActivity`* to its children views, in such a way that they normally respond (for example, if a child view has an `OnClickListener` set, and I send a generated down/up touch event to the child view, I'd like the `OnClickListener` to be called)?

Note that I'm not trying to send touch events from one activity to another, and that this is all in my own application. Also, my devices aren't rooted, so solutions requiring root don't help me.

Comment: take a look at the [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) class too

Comment: @FoamyGuy: Cool, that looks like it could be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out. The solution is to use [`Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29). For example, the following registered as a click event on my view:

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 200, 200, 0));
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 200, 200, 0));
```